# In a Visual Studio 2012 project, how can I avoid copying and pasting QT DLLs into executable directory?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012, dll, cmake

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to build a QT 5.5 application.

Note, I use CMake to generate the Visual Studio project and solution files.

If I build the Release solution, when I run the .exe I get an error complaining the dll's were not found.  I can fix this error, by copying and pasting the required dll's into the project's Release directory.

How can I avoid copying and pasting the required DLLs?

Do I need to specify the DLLs and/or their path in Visual Studio?

Is there a way to use CMake to specify the DLLs and/or their path?

Comment: For development: add their location to the PATH. For (end-user) deployment: putting them next to the application binary is usually the easiest and most robust solution. (Have a look at the windeploy tool)

Answer (score 1):

For providing the Qt DLL's along with your application, the `windeployqt` tool which comes with Qt itself is probably what you want. It knows about Qt's plugins, etc. and can copy in the relevant Qt DLL's and plugins for you. Depending on what you are trying to do, you may want to invoke it as either a post-build step, as an install step or both. There's also a `macdeployqt` tool for Mac OS X, but there is currently no equivalent `linuxdeployqt` tool.

For taking care of copying in any non-Qt DLL's, CMake's [`BundleUtilities` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/BundleUtilities.html) can be used to automatically copy in any DLL's that the executables/libraries depend on. Unlike the Qt-specific deploy tool, `BundleUtilities` works for all platforms, but it doesn't know anything about Qt plugins which would be loaded dynamically at run-time. Again, use the relevant function(s) from `BundleUtilities` as a post-build and/or install step. For Qt4, the [`DeployQt4`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/DeployQt4.html) module invokes `BundleUtilities` internally, but CMake doesn't provide an equivalent module for Qt5, instead choosing to let Qt itself provide the necessary support.